# Using more data sets in Report Server from one stored procedure

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am deploying a lot of report lately.
And so to I kept code and version clear and understanding, 
Ill like to  have one stored procedure per report.
Mostly time I need more data sets for one reports.
Is there possibility to I have more then one data set in report SSRS for calling only one stored procedure for that report.
(I am using remote reports hosted on Sql Report Server 2008 ).

I uses familiar Issue whit sample console application for creating multiple CSV files from  SQL using one stored procedure.
snipes of code looks something like this:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn); 
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sp_ado_pos_data", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Add("@skl_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 158;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            string datoteka  = (string.Format(@"{0}tablea{1}.csv", direktorij, i));
            DataTable tabela = ds.Tables[i];  
            //Here I fill datasets with multiple results from one stored proc.
            CreateCSVFile(tabela,datoteka );
            Console.WriteLine("Generišem tabelu {0}", datoteka);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this isn't possible with standard reports presented through the default report viewer - SSRS ignores all but the first result set from a multi result-set source.

However, based on [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/robo60/StandaloneRDLCReports11142007183516PM/StandaloneRDLCReports.aspx), it appears that it is be possible in stand-alone  reports (.rdlc extension). I'm not sure whether this means that, with a custom report viewer, standard .rdl reports could be configured in a similar way.